# Nginx: How to rewrite the path to the error page?

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have an `/api` location that contains an HTTP authorization. I want my 401 page to be displayed on failed authorization.

Here is my file structure (If it's important, I'm running nginx on Windows)

```
nginx
|─html
  |
  | 401.html
  |
  |─40x_files
    |
    | script.js
    | styles.css
```

Here is my config

```json
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;
 
    error_page 401 /401.html;
    location = /401.html {
        auth_basic off;
        root html;
    }

    location /api {
        auth_basic "Restricted area";
        auth_basic_user_file ../conf/conf.d/htpasswd;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;
    }
}
```

I got two problems

1. If I just type `example.com/401.html` in the browser, I get an error that it cannot access files in `40x_files` folder (here is filed of `401.html` page)
2. If I fail the authorization, then for some reason I am redirected to this path `api/40x_files/script.js`, how can I return it to correct state?

I suppose I need to do some kind of `rewrite`, but I don’t really understand how to arrange it correctly

Comment: Is there an entry in the access and error logs? "I get an error..." doesn't give us enough information. Also, your `401.html` is using `40x_files/script.js` to access its resource files instead of `/40x_files/script.js` (you're missing the leading `/`)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.